# Load Image From URL to Picasso

Tags: android, gridview, download, picasso

I wrote a wallpaper app for Android. I used Picasso for download, cache and show images from given URLs.

In mainActivity I have a Gridview which images load inside it.

And in ActivityTwo I have Imageview which shows the selected image
but the problem is that image load very very slowly (for example a 300Kb image load in 10 secs).

How can I make images load faster?

Here is my codes:

MainActivity.Java

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivityTwo.class);
                intent.putExtra("position", position);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }


    //    our custom adapter
    private class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context mContext;

        public ImageAdapter(Context context) {
            mContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mThumbIds.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView,
                            ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView imageView;
//            check to see if we have a view
            if (convertView == null) {
//                no view - so create a new one
                imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            } else {
//                use the recycled view object
                imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            }

//            Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).setDebugging(true);
            Picasso.with(MainActivity.this)
                    .load(mThumbIds[position])
                    .placeholder(R.raw.place_holder)
                    .error(R.raw.big_problem)
                    .noFade().resize(250, 250)
                    .into(imageView);

            return imageView;
        }
    }

    static String[] mThumbIds = {

            //My Links Here
    };
}
```

Comment: "How Can I Make Images Load Faster". The code is fine. If you want faster, get a faster server to serve the images or a faster internet connection for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Glide library. It loads images faster than Picasso library. For more details refer this [link.](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en) 
Libraries to include

`dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
}`

Use this to load images :

`Glide.with(context)
    .load("http://inthecheesefactory.com/uploads/source/glidepicasso/cover.jpg")
    .into(ivImg);`